# Display few html5 videos with custom controls on single webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I would like to display different HTML5 videos on a single grid-based webpage.
I'm currently using this code for custom controls: http://jsfiddle.net/MELVIN29/nkckLhjx/

JS is working when there is only one video but doesn't when I want to duplicate players. 

 
I've already looked for a solution on various topics but I have found nothing that suited. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}
  </style>
  <title></title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var overlay = document.getElementById('video-overlay');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var videoPlaying = false;
overlay.onclick = function() {
    if (videoPlaying) {
        video.pause();
        videoPlaying = false;
    }
    else {
        video.play();
        videoPlaying = true;
    }
}
}//]]>

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <video width="320" height="240" id='video'>
    <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div id='video-overlay'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A few things to be noted here. If you want to have mutliple videos, you want to use a CLASS handle and not an ID handle. ID's are unique to one DOM element. Then when the page is loaded you can cycle through each element (with a for loop) that has your CLASS and bind the onclick event function to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is create a CLASS name and assign it to each one of your videos. Remember, an ID is not needed.

I used the class name 'myvideo'.

**HTML**

```
// notice - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  vvvvvvvv  
<video width="320" height="240" class="myvideo">
    <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
// notice same class name - - - - - -  vvvvvvvv
<video width="320" height="240" class="myvideo">
    <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

*For demonstration purpose, I got rid of all the styles in your example along with the overlay since they are not needed at the moment.*

---

**ON TO THE JAVASCRIPT...**

First, you will need a handle to the videos. getElementsByClassName returns an array of the specified class.

```
var myvideos = document.getElementsByClassName('myvideo');
```

Now, we can loop through the array of 'myvideos' with a for loop.

```
for (i=0; i<myvideos.length; i++){
     // content
}
```

Next, we need to assign a boolean variable that belongs to each video element. This boolean will let us know if the video is playing or not.

```
for (i=0; i<myvideos.length; i++){
     // video is not playing on load, so we assign it false
     myvideos[i].playing = false;
}
```

Now we just need to bind the onclick function.

```
for (i=0; i<myvideos.length; i++){
   myvideos[i].playing = false;
   myvideos[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
      // note that this 'this' keyword refers to the object
      // that triggered the click event
      if (!this.playing){
         this.play();
         this.playing = true;
      } else {
         this.pause();
         this.playing = false;
      }
   }); 
}
```

Please know that this is not the only way to do this.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkckLhjx/3/)